# how to use javascript in form runat=server without sending request to the server?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, master-pages

my master page is inside a form runat="server" like this:

```
<body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
         <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

In one of my pages I added a textarea, a button (html controls, not ASP's), and some javascript code like this:

```
<textarea id="ContentTextArea" class="ContentTextArea" rows="2" cols="20"></textarea>
<button id="ClearButton" class="Button2" onclick="ClearButtonClick();">CLEAR</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ClearButtonClick() {
            document.getElementById("ContentTextArea").value = "";
        }
    </script>
```

I want the javascript code (which is clearing the textarea text) to run when the client click on the "clear" button without sending a request to the server, but because I have `<form id="Form1" runat="server">` in the master page the button submit the data to the server and the page is reloaded.

I must have `<form id="Form1" runat="server">` in my master page, but I also want to use JavaSctipt in my code that will run on the client side.

Thanks

EDIT:

my master page is:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Site.master.cs" Inherits="SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
        <div class="header">
             <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
                <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Items>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/ContactUs.aspx" Text="Contact Us"/>
                    </Items>
                </asp:Menu>
            </div>

            <div class="loginDisplay">
                <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                    <AnonymousTemplate>
                        [ <a href="~/Account/Login.aspx" ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a> ]
                    </AnonymousTemplate>
                    <LoggedInTemplate>
                        Welcome <span class="bold"><asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" /></span>!
                        [ <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="~/"/> ]
                    </LoggedInTemplate>
                </asp:LoginView>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>

        <div class="main">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
        </div>

        <div class="footer">
            <p>GH Electronics © 2012. All Rights Reserved.</p>
        </div>

    </form>
    <input type="button" onclick="window.location = '/WareHouse/ContactUs.aspx';" value="avi"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">

           function ClearButtonClick() {
            document.getElementById("ContentTextArea").value = "";
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</body>


</html>
```

and my contact us form is:

> ```
> <img alt="Contact Us" src="Images/contact_us.gif" style="float:left;"/>
>
> <p class="contactUs" runat="server">CONTACT US</p>
> <label>Full Name:</label>
> <asp:TextBox class="FullNameTextBox" runat="server" />
> <br /> <br />
> <label>Phone Number:</label>
> <asp:TextBox class="PhoneNumberTextBox" runat="server" />
> <br /> <br />
> <label>Email:</label>
> <asp:TextBox class="EmailTextBox" runat="server" />
> <br /> <br />
> <label>Subject:</label>
> <asp:TextBox class="SubjectTextBox" runat="server" />
> <br /> <br />
> <label>Content:</label>
> <textarea id="ContentTextArea" class="ContentTextArea" rows="2" cols="20"></textarea>
> <br /> <br />
> <asp:Button ID="SendButton" class="SendButton" Text="SEND" runat="server" />
>
>
> <button id="ClearButton" class="Button2" onclick="ClearButtonClick();">CLEAR</button>
>
> <script type="text/javascript">
>
>       function ClearButtonClick() {
>        document.getElementById("ContentTextArea").value = "";
>        return false;
>    }
> ```

Comment: I see nothing in your markup that would perform a postback to the server.

Comment: Can you please post all your source code?

Comment: Still not seeing anything that would auto postback.  And this only happens when you click on the 'CLEAR' button?  What if you remove everything in the child page except the button?  That should help eliminate the button as a the culprit.

Comment: @Chris Gessler thanks for trying to help. I solved it by doing as Steen and Adil suggested. I don't know why it didn't work the other day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think this should do it:

```
<button id="ClearButton" class="Button2" onclick="javascript:ClearButtonClick();return false;">CLEAR</button>
```

Comment: see to that the button does not have runat="server"

Comment: <button> tag is not a submit button to begin with and it's not a server-side control.  There's no reason it should be posting back in the first place, or submitting the form.

Comment: @ChrisGessler - your right, I don't see it either.... but when remi says it submits, I suggest what could solve.

Comment: @Chris Gessler so why it is submitting the form?

Comment: @remi - some jQuery binding on the page??

Comment: @Steen - you'll have to post all the source of the child page (and possibly the master page) to determine why it's posting back.

Comment: @Steen I just posten my master page and the other page

Comment: Take a look at this fiddle - possible it has nothing to do with your problem, but notice how one of the buttons triggers post and the other one dosent: http://jsfiddle.net/kZ8ES/

Comment: @Steen Thanks you. your example made one thing important to me which is that I should have put `return false;` after calling the function `ClearButtonClick()`  instead of calling the function and writing in it `return false` which is not good since I didn't call the function with a `return` before the call .

Comment: @Steen altough I tried to it the other day but it didn't work and now it does.. I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this. You have to make changes at two places.

1. Add return in onclick="return ClearButtonClick();" event registration given below.

   ```
     <button id="ClearButton" class="Button2" onclick="return ClearButtonClick();">CLEAR</button>
   ```
2. Return false from javascript function to stop it from send request to server
   Put this in end of page or between head tag.

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       function ClearButtonClick() {
           document.getElementById("ContentTextArea").value = "";
           return false;
       }
   </script>
   ```

Comment: put it after </asp:Content>. I would recommend to put it just before the closing tag of body

Comment: I put it just before the closing tag of the body but from unknown reason the page is still submitted..

Comment: Do you have return false in ClearButtonClick() definition and onclick="return ClearButtonClick(); in button definition also add alert in ClearButtonClick() to assure it is being called

Comment: you are right, I should have write `onclick="return ClearButtonClick();` instead of `onclick="ClearButtonClick();`. Thanks